# react-router v6 double rendering components

Tags: typescript, react-router, create-react-app, single-page-application

This is my first CRA/ typescript, SPA project so apologies if this is a beginner question. Initially, all my routing is going to be handled via my navbar.

Thus far when you click the navbar you do get the component at the top of the screen as desired but if you scroll down you also get the repeated initial page layout.

So my question is how do I anchor my nav links to a component rather than just bringing that component to the top of the page to be repeated again.
Below is a link to my code.

index.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import './index.scss';
import App from './components/App/App';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Gallery from './components/Gallery/Gallery';
import About from './components/About/About';


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/gallery" element={<Gallery />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

App.jsx

```
import './App.scss';
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from '../NavBar/NavBar.tsx';
import About from '../About/About.tsx';
import GalleryCard from '../Gallery/Gallery.tsx';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';


const App = () => {
  const background =  require("../../assets/images/45-degree-fabric-light.png")

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='background'>
        <img src={background} className='background' alt="background" />
      </div>
      <NavBar/>
      <Divider className='divider' textAlign="left">GALLERY</Divider>
      <div className='card-container'>
        <GalleryCard/>
      </div>
      <Divider className='divider' textAlign="left">ABOUT</Divider>
      <About/>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

NavBar.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, Outlet} from "react-router-dom";
import HomeButton from './HomeButton';
import './navbar.scss';


const NavBar = () => {

    return (
        <>
        <nav className='nav-container'>
      <Link to='/'><HomeButton/></Link>
            <div className='inner-container'>
                <div className='nav-links'>
                    <Link to='/' className='nav-link' >Home</Link>
                    <Link to='/gallery' className='nav-link' >Gallery</Link>
                    <Link to='/about' className='nav-link' >About</Link>
                    <Link to='/videos' className='nav-link' >Videos</Link>
                    <Link to='/contact' className='nav-link' >Contact</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <Outlet />
        </>
    )

}
export default NavBar;
```

Comment: Shouldn't be App on top of all?
App + Navbar
  / ->             Landing
  /about ->    About
  /gallery ->   Gallery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GalleryCard` and `About` components are rendered twice because they are rendered in two places.

index

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />     // <-- here
    <Route path="/gallery" element={<Gallery />} /> // <-- here
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

App

```
const App = () => {
  const background =  require("../../assets/images/45-degree-fabric-light.png")

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='background'>
        <img src={background} className='background' alt="background" />
      </div>
      <NavBar/>
      <Divider className='divider' textAlign="left">GALLERY</Divider>
      <div className='card-container'>
        <GalleryCard/> // <-- and here
      </div>
      <Divider className='divider' textAlign="left">ABOUT</Divider>
      <About/> // <-- and here
    </div>
  );
}
```

Remove them from `App`, replace them with an `Outlet` component so the nested routes render out there in their place.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const App = () => {
  const background =  require("../../assets/images/45-degree-fabric-light.png")

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='background'>
        <img src={background} className='background' alt="background" />
      </div>
      <NavBar/>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Move the divider and title to the components.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This works but then it renders in distinct pages, which might not be a bad direction to take it, but what I was originally shooting for was a single page application where the nav links jumped you to the portion of the page.

Comment: @Tori I see, then don't use `react-router-dom` and render different pages on different routes. `react-router-dom@6` doesn't handle linking to hashlinks. So all you want to do is render a single page and slide the sections into view?

Comment: Sliding to different sections is exactly what I was attempting to do, I didn't know that `react-router-dom` doesn't handle linking to hashlinks.

Comment: @Tori If you don't mind using an older version of `react-router-dom` (v5) there is [react-router-hash-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) that *does* do what you are asking. You wouldn't render routes for these components but the hash linking would work. I can create an example if you like/need.

Comment: No worries, I was looking at how to do hash-links and the more I think about it the more I think I prefer the distinct page routing. I'll just have to change my design a bit. But thank you again so much for the help on this I really appreciate it!